# Cart Price Discount according to quantity value

Tags: php

How can i apply 5% discount in base price after Quantity cross 15 in custom e Commerce.

Code:

```
$price = $_POST['price'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$discount = $_POST['discount'];
$tax = $_POST['tax'];
$shipping = $_POST['shipping'];
$payments = $_POST['payments'];

$total = (($price * $quantity) + $shipping) - $discount;
```

Comment: Show us some code..

Comment: i can share this file with you will you please provide me your email id

Comment: No, you're alright thanks. Just post some sample code in your questions with what you've tried already.

Comment: $price = $_POST['price'];
20  $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
21  $discount = $_POST['discount'];
22  $tax = $_POST['tax'];
23  $shipping = $_POST['shipping'];
24  $payments = $_POST['payments'];
25
26  
27  $total = (($price * $quantity) +
    $shipping) - $discount;

Comment: post your code in the question and format it correctly

Comment: this platform is to help you with development issues, kindly post a sample code. Its not a freelancing platform where one will debug your issues

Answer (score -2):

```
    $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $_POST['price']);  
    $quantity =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $_POST['quantity']);

    if ($quantity > 15)
    {
      $discount = ($price/100)*5;
      $price = $price - $discount;
    }

    else 
    {
      $price = $price;
    }
```

Comment: @RajatKumar Please select this as answer.